# R package for feature set algorithm selection

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, feature-selection

I want to train a binary classification NN and part of this will require data pre-processing. However, I have a choice of which pre-processing algorithm to use. Of course I'd like to choose that one which is maximally informative for the purposes of training the NN. I feel sure that there might be some R package that I could us for this selection purpose, so could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cross-validate the entire algorithm, feature selection included.  The `train` function in the [caret](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/Classification_and_Regression_Training.html) package offers many pre-processing options, the effects of which are included in the cross validation loop.